# What does this REGEX means? [a-zA-Z]|\d

Tags: regex

What is the meaning of this regex? [a-zA-Z]|\d

I know that [a-zA-Z] means all of a to Z chars but whats the mean of \d?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\d` is a digit character.  Your code means "any alphabetic or numeric character".  It could more easily be expressed as `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: @ShirazITCo, `\d` can match far more than 0-9. In a Unicode-aware regex engine (such as Perl's), it matches [420 characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm).

Answer (score 4):

\d just means a digit character, it is equivalent to [0-9].

Here's a good reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 3):

In most regex flavors, `\d` means any numeric digit, and is the same as `[0-9]`.

Your regex as a whole means "match either a single letter of the alphabet, or a single digit."

Comment: Since `\d` has an equivalent character class you can combine them into a single character class as lonesomeday shows.

Answer (score 3):

`\d` matches any digits.

Answer (score 3):

\d matches any digit ( i.e. 0-9 ). 
See for example [regular expression list](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

\d means digit and is synonymous with [0-9]. As I type this I see this question is answered twice more, and I bet with the same information.

My favorite books on regex are
[http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/1565922573](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565922573)
and 
[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Regular-Expressions-Programmer/dp/0764574892/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1305497415&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574892)

they are such a powerful thing to master.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon what your goal is, you might be able to replace that with \w which is a "word character" i.e. any letter, digit or the underscore character.